# difference between bash, -bash and /bin/bash in ps output

Tags: bash, ps

Someone had spawned a while true loop in bash (logged in as root) on a server. It kept spawning processes, which fortunately exited but I needed to kill the parent. I came to know it was spawned directly from command line and not from a script, so I grepped for '-bash' and killed those processes owned by root. It worked fine.

When you do `ps aux`, In the command column different variants of bash show up.

```
/bin/bash
-bash
-bash
-bash
/bin/bash
bash
/bin/bash
/bin/bash
bash
```

etc..

What are the differences?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. @swair is asking what the difference between `-bash` and `/bin/bash` is, not what the difference between a login shell and non-login shell is. The answer to this question is, "`-bash` denotes a login shell and `/bin/bash` denotes a non-login shell." The answer to the other question is a list of differences between login shells and non-login shells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The leading dash indicates a login shell, from `man bash`:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`, or one started with the `--login` option.
>
> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading  that  file,  it  looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.

`bash` and `/bin/bash` are the same, they just were invoked differently (the former was not invoked using the full path).

Comment: I swear i looked up the man page before posting. Missed this part :(. Thanks for the answer!